# Neo4j neo4j No operations allowed until you send an INIT message successfully

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-dotnet-driver

Using WebApiConfig.Neo4jDriver.Session.Run(...) an error is thrown.

"No operations allowed until you send an INIT message successfully".

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a permissions issue.

Try setting `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` in neo4j.conf, or add authentication credentials to your application.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that you're not authenticated. Perhaps your **password has changed**, either in your application config, or when you recreated your neo4j server?

See https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/issues/119#issuecomment-239099794